# FaceBook Connect not redirecting to next page after authentication

Tags: facebook

In one of the projects which has been given to me for maintanence, I can see the following code being used to login to FaceBook using FaceBook connect.

The issue is after clicking the facebook connect button, the facebook login popup window appears and after authentication the popup window does not close and the next page will not get opened instead of the main page.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            FB.init("[app_key]", "xd_receiver.htm");
            function FBLoginPerms(apiKey, redirect){
                FB.Connect.requireSession(
                    function() {
                        FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email,user_photos,read_friendlists,publish_stream,user_birthday", function() {window.location = redirect;});
                    }
                );
            }


        </script>

        <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/myapp/login.php" onclick="FBLoginPerms(&#39;[app_key]&#39;,&#39;/myapp/thankyou.php&#39;); return false;">
            <img src="facebook_login.png" alt="" border="0" />
        </a>
```

Comment: it seems that you should set redirect url

Comment: The redirect url is given while calling the following method FBLoginPerms(&#39;[app_key]&#39;,&#39;/myapp/thankyou.php&#39;); return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB.Connect is deprecated and is not supported.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/

Try using the new login/logout of the new SDK

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/